# Fetch title attribute of each input element on a page and echo / print it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to list all of the title attributes for every input field on a page with a large number of input elements (I'm re factoring the code). They can be echoed in the HTML (i.e. breaking site design isn't important).

I've tried:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    if (element.getAttribute("title").val()!= '') {
        System.out.println(element.getAttribute("title"));
    }
}
```

In an attempt to list the elements in the console, but I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Whatever you have tried is not even near to Javascript, that's Java which is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote Java, not Javascript. [They are not related, read more](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html).

Anyways, here is javascript (jQuery):

I create an `ul` with id `nameList` and append it to the body. Then I use `.each` on a selector that gets all inputs who HAVE name attribute and append the name as a `li` in my `ul#nameList`:

```
//create ul with id nameList, set bullet type and append on body
$('<ul />').attr('id', 'nameList').css('list-style','square').appendTo('body'); 

//cache it to use on the below each
$nameList = $('ul#nameList');

//each input with attribute name set
$('input[name]').each(function(index, el) {
    //create a li, put the current input's name (this) as a text and append to our ul
    $('<li />').text($(this).attr('name')).appendTo($nameList);
});
```

Scroll past the inputs to see list:

http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/BQ7Mt/2/

Comment: Sorry - what a stupid mix up on my part: although I know Java and javascript are unrelated, I am unfamiliar with Java so thought this was some syntax of jQuery I just hadn't run into yet - now I look at it it's obviously not. I was tired when posting - thank you very much for the jQuery, works great.